# iOS 6 oreiantation in iphone ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

How to set the orientation in ios6 for iphone and ipad, i tried with the following coding, its not showing any response.

//following not working because of deprecated issue

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
  {
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];
  }
if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)
 {
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];
 }

 return YES;

}
```

// ios6 coding for ipad and iphone

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];
}
```

it doesn't showing any change. i just want to change the back ground while change the orientation? can any one please help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place "return" as the last statement.
edit: but the color changes are wrong in there as well, take a look at [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: yeah i tried ... but image is not changing wen its changed for portrait

Comment: supportedInterfaceOrientations returns the Bitmask for all the orientations you want to support?

Comment: you need a didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: {self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];}